# Overlay icons working in file browser but not in file explorer

Tags: windows, icons, windows-xp, overlay, tortoisecvs

I work with TortoiseCVS and for some reason overlay icons are not showing in windows explorer. The weird part is that in any Office app or VisualStudio, if I click 'open file' the overlay icons are showing in the file browser. But not if I open 'my computer' and go to my local disc.. I looked in the registry and my tortoise overlay icon are named 1, 2, 3,... so I cannot fix the problem this way. I also uninstaled all CVS related programs, reboot, reinstal, reboot and still can't see overlay icons expet in an application file browser. I haven't seen any post yet with this problem so I tought I'd post it up here see if anyone know about it. 
running Windows XP SP3.

David

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 64 bit XP? I had a similar problem in 64-bit Windows 7. I renamed all my unused icon overlays in the registry file to start with z_ and restarted; the Tortoise CVS overlays showed up in the Explorer view but not in the actual folder view.

Glen Starrett on the TortoiseCVS mailing list told me there were overlay keys for x32 and x64. I checked the x32 location and noticed all the Tortoise icons were first (key names began with 0-9). I tried Glen's suggestion of prepending my x64 Tortoise overlays with 00 instead of prepending the unused overlays with z_ (since MS updates might rename the keys anyway). When I did this and rebooted, the CVS overlays showed up properly in the folder view.